Problem installing @solana/spl-token @solana/web3.js
I want to deploy and interact with a NFT solana program.
As recommanded by the documentation I am using this code https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/nft-minter/native/
I am on WSL and when I try to install the js packages @solana/spl-token @solana/web3.js I have these errors:
npm install --save @solana/spl-token @solana/web3.js  
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL  
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*

When I use yarn I have these errors:
yarn add @solana/spl-token @solana/web3.js
➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.1.1
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0001: │ Error: @solana/fast-stable-stringify@workspace:*: Workspace not found (@solana/fast-stable-stringify@workspace:*)

When I use pnpm
 pnpm install
 WARN  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/borsh error (ECONNRESET). Will retry in 10 seconds. 2 retries left.
Downloading typescript@4.9.5: 11.62 MB/11.62 MB, done
 ERR_PNPM_WORKSPACE_PKG_NOT_FOUND  In : "@solana/fast-stable-stringify@workspace:*" is in the dependencies but no package named "@solana/fast-stable-stringify" is present in the workspace

This error happened while installing the dependencies of @solana/web3.js@1.91.5


Could you share your package.json file

This was a bug reverted with https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/pull/2509, so be sure to use 1.91.6 at least
